getting #document (about: blank) when using embed tag with svg
I am trying to embed svg in my document so I can style the svg with external stylesheet bt using object tag or embed I run into the problem of the svg document not loading either with object.getElementById("object") nor with loading into embed tag
embed code
<div id="paraone">
    <div class="righthand-graphics-container">
         <embed id="infographic" data="path to svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
         <embed id="infographic-0" data="path to svg" type="image/svg+xml" />
    </div><p></p>
</div>

I have tried resolving it with suggestions from copilot but the file path is correct should not be permissions I can load it into img tag and object however object tag has similar issue probably same if I figure it out. When I look under developer tools network tab the file does not show just not attempting to get the file or no problem getting the file and somehow not loading.
I need some wise heads who might have seen this problem :)

embed uses the src attribute, not data. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/embed

Make sure that you are running this from a webserver, not directly from the file system.
